# Removal of duplicates in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

For this assignment, I am to write a method removeDuplicates that takes as a parameter a sorted ArrayList of Strings and that eliminates any duplicates from the list.

For example, suppose that a variable called list contains the following values:

```
{"be", "be", "is", "not", "or", "question", "that", "the", "to", "to"}
```

After calling removeDuplicates(list), the list should store the following values:

```
{"be", "is", "not", "or", "question", "that", "the", "to"}
```

I almost have it down, but for some reason, if the list contains

```
["duplicate", "duplicate", "duplicate", "duplicate", "duplicate"]
```

it would remove all but two, resulting in [duplicate, duplicate] instead of [duplicate]

Here's my code:

```
private static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<String> thing) {
    for (int i = 0; i < thing.size(); i++) { // base word to compare to
        String temp = thing.get(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < thing.size(); j++) { // goes through list for match
            String temp2 = thing.get(j);

            if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase(temp2) && i != j) { // to prevent removal of own letter.
                thing.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Try stepping through your code using that small example, and keep an eye on how `thing.size()` changes after each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you do "j++" even when you find a duplicate. Once you do a "thing.remove(j);" it essentially shifts everything down one index value, so you don't have to increase j.

Example:

```
{ duplicate, duplicate, duplicate, duplicate, duplicate }

i iteration 1:
i=0 [dup, dup, dup, dup, dup]
j=0 [dup, dup, dup, dup, dup]
remove=1
j=1 [dup, dup, dup, dup]
remove=2
j=2 [dup, dup, dup]

i iteration 2:
i=1 [dup, dup, dup]
remove=0
j=0 [dup, dup]
j=1 [dup, dup]

[dup, dup]

i iteration 3 stops since 3>size of list.
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time it removes an entry in the ArrayList, its size decrements.

So `thing.size()` will decrease.

Answer (score 0):

Will give you a Java Collections trick:  convert your List to a Set , which will by definition only keep unique values, then convert it back to a List again.